# Queen's graph diameter and knight's graph diameter for a $n \times n \times \dots \times n$ chessboard

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, recreational-mathematics, integers, chessboard

Let a $n \times n \times n$ chessboard be given. I have just proven (by brute force) that, the queen's graph diameter, ${d_{n}^k}(Q)$ (i.e., the number of moves needed to move a queen from any 3D cell of the given chessboard to another cell belonging to the same chessboard, as the worst-case scenario), is equal to zero iff $n = 1$, ${d_{n}^3}(Q) = 1$ iff $n = 2$, ${d_{n}^3}(Q) = 2$ iff $n \in \{3,4,5\}$, and ${d_{n}^k}(Q) = 3$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Now, by considering any $k$-dimensional $n \times n \times n$ chessboard, it is trivial to point out that ${d_{n}^k}(Q) \leq k$ for any $n, k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ (since the rook's graph diameter is equal to $k$ for any $k$-dimensional chessboard such that $n \geq 2$).

My **first question** is as follows:
"For any given $k \geq 2$, is it possible to prove the existence of a minimum value of $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that ${d_{n}^k}(Q) = k$ (e.g., if $k = 2$, then $n = 3$; if $k = 3$, then $n = 6$, and so forth)?"

**Second question**: "Let $n \geq 4$ and $k \geq 2$ be given. Which is the knight's graph diameter, ${d_{n}^k}(N)$, for a generic, $k$-dimensional, $n \times n \times \dots \times n$ board (e.g., ${d_{n}^k}(K)=n-1$ would describe the king's graph diameter and ${d_{n}^k}(R)=k$ returns the rook's graph diameter for the same $k$-dimensional board)?".

As a footnote, I would also note that the pawn's graph diameter is equal to $n - 2 + {d_{n}^k}(Q)$ for any $n \geq 4$, while I strongly conjecture that the knight's graph diameter, for any given $n \times n \times n$ 3D chessboard such that $n \geq 4$, is equal to $n$ (moreover, we can easily show that $\lceil{\frac{(n - 1) \cdot \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{5}}}\rceil \leq {d_{n}^k}(N) \leq (n + 1) \cdot k$ holds for any $n$ as above and that $\lceil{\frac{(n - 1) \cdot \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{5}}}\rceil \leq {d_{n}^k}(N) \leq n \cdot k$ is true for any odd value of $n : n > 4$, while the OEIS sequence A232007 entirely covers the planar case).

Comment: In a 3D board, can the queen's diagonal motion be extended to a three-dimension diagonal, or must she stay on one orthogonal plane?

Comment: The "tower" is a rook in English.

Comment: The knights move can change the sum of the vectors by $-3,-1,1,3.$ So the distance from $(1,1,\dots,1)$ to $(n,n,\dots,n)$ has to change the sum $k$ to the sum $kn,$ and has to be at least distance $$D=\left\lceil\frac{n(k-1)}{3}\right\rceil,$$ but you also need $D$ the same parity as $n(k-1),$ so this distance has lower bound $D$ or $D+1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, The queen (and also the king or even the bishop) can move from $(0,0,\dots,0)$ to $(1,1,\dots,1)$ by spending just one move, so the answer is affirmative.

Comment: @joriki, I'll edit tower-->rook right now (we have already used ${d_{n}^k}(R)$ for the rook's graph).

Comment: I guess the knight move generalization depends on how you think about the planar knight move. I always think of it as one orthogonal move two spaces and another on space. But you can also think of the knight's move as one diagonal move and one orthogonal move in one of the directions as the diagonal move. So can you move from $(1,1,1)$ to$(2,2,3)?$ ($(1,1,1)$ diagonally to $(2,2,2)$ and then one additional to $(2,2,3) ,$ or does a generalized knight move only change two coordinates?

Comment: We are implicitly stating that the knight moves are planar, characterized by a fixed Euclidean distance equal to $\sqrt{5}$ (moreover, in this old paper of mine [ https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/view/10106/5997 ] I've achieved something interesting by following the aforementioned approach, see Figures 4&5 ).

Comment: BTW, in our case, we assume that any knight move necessarily changes by $2$ the value of one coordinate and by $1$ the value of another one (e.g., $(2,2,2,2,...,2) \rightarrow (0,2,3,2,...,2)$ or $(2,2,2,2,...,2) \rightarrow (2,4,1,2,...,2)$ are both fine for a $n \times n \times \dots \times n$ board, since $n : n \geq 4$ by hypothesis).

Comment: You can restrict to a starting point of $(1,1,\dots,1)$ and compute the largest distance from there. This is if the two nodes are $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_k)$ we can reflect the cube until you get an equivalent pair, with each $a_i\leq b_i,$ then translate to $(1,1,\dots,1)$ and $(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ with $c_i=b_i-a_i+1.$ Then any path from $(1,\dots,1)$ to $(c_i)$ goes to an equivalent path from $(a_i)$ to $(b_i).$ So we know a maximum path is from $(1,\dots,1).$

Comment: Good point, Thomas. I think that your comment deserves to be posted as a (partial) answer... so I can also give you a few reputation points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142102/discussion-between-marco-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: @marco I was a bit too quick on the knight's diameter being maximized from a corner. I think it is true, but as the other corner moves away from a side, it adds paths, so it is a slightly tricker argument to make. In particular, when $n=3,$ there is no knight's path from the the center to any other square, but if we translate the center to the corner, there are certainly paths to others. But I think we can find an argument for this which will work when $n>3,$ ensuring that we can restrict to pairs starting in the corner.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, just posting to revisit later.

We will write $(0,0,\dots,0)$ for one corner, to make some of the math cleaner.

I can't quite prove that minimal paths starting from $(0,0,\dots,0)$ will give the diameter, but I have an intuition for that, at least when $n$ is somewhat large.

If we are looking for the knight's distance $d$ from $(0,0,\dots,0)$ to $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$ we want to solve:

$$a_i=-2u_i-1v_i+w_i+2x_i$$

where $u_i, v_i,w_i,x_i$ are non-negative integers and $$\sum_i(u_i+x_i)=\sum_i(v_i+w_i)\tag1=d$$

You also need $v_i+w_i\leq \sum_{j\neq i} (u_j+x_j)$ or: $$u_i+w_i+v_i+x_i\leq d\tag2$$ If $(2)$ were false, then the dimension $i$ would be part of more than $d$ moves.

The obvious goal is to minimize the use of negative values.

Write $u=\sum u_i,$ and likewise for $v,w,x.$ $(1)$ can be written as $u+w=v+x=d.$

If $a_1 + \cdots + a_k=M$ and $M=3m,$ we can write $3m=m+2m,$ so we might try to get $u=v=0, w=x=m,$ and try to solve our equations with length $\ell=m.$

If $a_1 + \cdots + a_k=3m+1,$ we can write $3m+1=2(m+1)+m+(-1)$ so we might get a path of length $\ell =m+1$ with $u=0, v=1, w=m, x=m+1.$

In the case of $3m+2,$ you get $3m+2=2(m+1)+(m+2)-2,$ and we want $u=1, v=0, w=m+2, x=m+1,$ and we might find a path of length $\ell=m+2.$

Now, if $$\sum\left\lfloor \frac{a_i}2\right\rfloor\geq \ell\tag3$$
we can partition the $\ell$ $2$s amongst each dimension, and then dive out the $1s.$

For example, if $k=4, n=5$ and we are finding a path from $(0,0,0,0)$ to $(5,5,4,3)$ we get a sum of $17=3\cdot 5+2$ and thus a minimum length of $7.$ We satisfy $(3),$ so write:

$$a_1=2+2+1\\
a_2=2+2+1\\
a_3=2+2+(-2)+1+1\\
a_4=1+1+1 $$

Then we get a path:

$$(1,0,2,0)+\\
(0,1,2,0)+\\
(0,0,-2,1)+\\
(2,0,1,0)+\\
(2,0,1,0)+\\
(0,2,0,1)+\\
(0,2,0,1)=(5,5,4,3)$$

So we have the distance to $(5,4,3,2)$ is $7$.

The problem of $(3)$ rears its ugly head, though. The path from $(0,0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1,1)$ is more complicated. Two moves is not enough. But it will still be a lot less than going to a point near the far corner, at least for relatively large $n.$ The minimal path in this case will be  $$(1,2,0,0)+(0,0,1,2)+(0,1,0,-2)+(0,-2,0,1)=(1,1,1,1)$$

The maximum path will be to $(n-1,\dots,n-1)$ if $k(n-1)\equiv 2\pmod 3,$ and then the diameter will be $2+\left\lfloor \frac {k(n-1)}3\right\rfloor.$

When $k(n-1)\equiv 0,1\pmod 3$ then the diameter will be $1+\left\lfloor\frac{k(n-1)}3\right\rfloor,$ with endpoint $(n-1,n-1,\dots,n-1)$ in the $\equiv 1$ case, and $(n-1,n-1,\dots,n-1,n-2)$ in the $\equiv 0$ case.

Comment: Just to say that this useful comment has been included as a reference in my last preprint on the arXiv [https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.00016], many thanks!